Horizontal lines appear in the cycle render when using principle volume for the material
If I delete the object with principal volume, the Cycle render will work fine.
I tried lowering the volume step rates render to 0.01 and increasing the max sample, but it did not work. How can I get rid of those lines?


That seems very unusual. Is the volume object unusual shape, or is it just a primitive like a cube?

They are cubes. One used principle volume and one used volume scatter as material. I turned off my sun light, and these lines disappeared.

Wait, multiple cubes with different materials?
